# How to normalise data for a k-s test?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, stat

I have two numpy arrays which have different sizes and I want to run a k-s test on them, but before I do this I need to normalise them. Is the any way to do this? The arrays I have are similar to the ones below:

```
size1 = array1.size 
print(size1) 
120

size2 = array2.size 
print(size2)
111
```

All the values in each array are between -1 and +1, and Ive been able to plot them in a historgram easily, but is there anyway to **normalise both the arrays to unity outside of the histogram** such that I can use the scipy module `scipy.stats.ks_2samp` to run a ks test on both the arrays?

in the end I would like something similar to the following:

```
kstest = scipy.stats.ks_2samp(array1norm, array2norm)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. In the scipy doc, it does not say anything about requirements of arrays. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by normalizing? Do you want to map them to a specific interval, like (0, 1)?

Comment: When I say normalise I mean when I plot them in a histogram I normalise it so the sum of the areas under the histogram is equal to 1, that way I can compare the distributions correctly

Answer (score 0):

> I have two numpy arrays which have different sizes and I want to run a k-s test on them, but before I do this I need to normalise them. Is the any way to do this?

No. The premise is false, though. There is no need to adjust for the arrays being different sizes before performing the test. Just perform the test:

```py
scipy.stats.ks_2samp(array1, array2)
```